# How to convert time zone within mysql statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to convert a unix timestamp into a local time using mysql.

The statement I am trying is:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('FROM_UNIXTIME(table1.timestamp)', 'GMT', 'MET' ),table1.COL2,table1.COL3 WHERE table1ID ='3'
```

It returns `NULL`.

I would prefer to do this directly in mysql rather than manipulating the output later using php to keep other parts of my code simple.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: By doing this in MySQL you're introducing coupling and unnecessary complexity. You *should* do this in PHP and just use your database for storage / calculations / relations as it's supposed to be used.

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove the quotation on your `'FROM_UNIXTIME(table1.timestamp)'` like:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(FROM_UNIXTIME(table1.timestamp), 'GMT', 'MET' ),table1.COL2,table1.COL3 WHERE table1ID ='3'
```

Answer (score 0):

Quotes around `FROM_UNIXTIME(table1.timestamp)` make that a string, which does not look like a date. You have to remove the quotes to make it a function call.

Once that is done, you still might get `NULL`.
Test it out by running a test query: `SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2004-01-01 12:00:00','GMT','MET');`

If you still get `NULL`, you probably need to set up your time zone tables.
See [MySQL documentation on topic](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html).